# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iplot'

Tags: python, attributes, plotly

I am writing a code for the analysis and visualization of .csv data on kivy platform. Firstly, I write a function, the function is basically to clean the .csv data and print it. For printing the data it has to be converted in to string otherwise the code is generating error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Once I converted the type [class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'] into [class 'str'] the code works fine and print the data. Now, the issue is when I try to plot the data with the help of Plotly it is generating error. The code along with error is given below.

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
a=function("abc.csv")
b=str(a[["C","Q"]])
b.iplot()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3555b8b8f48f> in <module>()
      1 b=str(a[["C","Q"]])
----> 2 b.iplot()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iplot'
```

Comment: Where is the first error coming from? The error message tells you what you have to do. Converting it to a string is not the correct solution (e.g. you probably want to call `.item()` instead), but the context in which you got the error is not entirely clear on the first place. Typically when asking for help with an error in Python it is informative to post the *full traceback* leading up to the exception message as that will give experts more information about what you tried to do that led up to the exception.

Comment: Hi, the first error is from kivy platform I will update it in my post as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. `iplot` isn't a method of the string object, it's a function. It should be `iplot(b)`

Whether or not this will work with your data after conversion to string I'm not sure, try it and see. If not you could always just call `iplot(a[["C","Q"]])`

Comment: Hi, I check it before there is no syntax issue in using b.iplot(). Its working well when I don't convert the data into string. For E.g: b=a[["C","Q"]]  
b.iplot() works fine on Python.

Comment: What is `function` in your code? It returns the object you have called `a` and evidently whatever type of object this is it has an iplot method (or at least the objects returned by indexing it do). When you pass an object to `str()` you get back a string object which you have called `b`. The string object doesn't have an iplot method. If `a[["C","Q"]].iplot()` is working then why not just use that to make the plot and `b` to print to screen?

Comment: Hi Simon, the (function) class is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.  I try to use a[["C","Q"]].iplot()  on Jupyter Notebook environment. The code is generating a plot with following errors:[INFO ] [GL ] NPOT texture support is available [ERROR ] unable to access to <\pagefile.sys> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 178, in is_hidden return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx',